# testing a string to create a valid password

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement, methods, error-handling

I am creating a java program to test the validity of a password. In addition to some other problems, I flat out can't run it. It compiles fine, but I get an error when I try and run it.

When I get it to run, my problem is that I am unable to get my code to work like it should. It needs to read a user input string and test it for validity using some conditions laid out by the code. It will keep running until the user enters a valid password which fits all three conditions. The code, when it ran previously, would tell that the wrong condition was compromised, or would say that the password was invalid when it met every requirement.

I'm not quite sure how to ask what is wrong with my code, because I don't know the problem.

The pre-condition is that I use several methods in my code.

Here is my code so far:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // Prompt user to enter a password
        System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
        String x = input.nextLine();
        UserInput(x);
        
    }    
    
    public static String UserInput(String x) {
        
        // Define variables
        int l = x.length(),
                count = 0;
        
        char n = x.charAt(l);
        
        boolean valid = false,
                condition = false;
        
        String c1 = "", 
               s1 = "";
        
        
        // While loop tests the validity of the password
        while(valid == false && l <= 0){ 
            
            if (l < 8){
                condition = false;
                c1 = "A password must have at least eight characters";
                continue;
            }
            else if (Character.isLetter(n) == false && Character.isDigit(n) == false){
                condition = false;
                c1 = "A password must consist of only letters and digits";
                continue;
            }
            else
                condition = true;
            
            while (count < 2) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(n) == true) {
                        count++;
                    }
            }
            
            if (count < 2) {
                condition = false;
                c1 = "A password must contain at least two digits";
                continue;
            }
            
            else {
                condition = true;
            }
            
            l++;
            
            if (condition = true)
                valid = true;
            else
                valid = false;
        }
        
        if (valid == true)
            s1 = "Valid Passord";
        else
            s1 = "Invalid Password";
        
        String m = s1 + "\n\t" + c1;
        System.out.println(m);
        return x;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set password length -

```
int l = x.length(),
```

Then loop based on it.

```
    while(valid == false && l <= 0){
```

Is "Loop while ...the password length is less than or equal to zero" what you meant?

Also, for checking minimum digits (please check my syntax) -

```
int ndx = 0;
while (ndx < l) { 
  if ( Character.isDigit( x.charAt( ndx++ ) ) ) {
     count++;
  }
}
```

Base the loop on the characters you check, not what you expect to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (count < 2) {
                if (Character.isDigit(n) == true) {
                    count++;
                }
        }
```

In this loop you check one character, if last char of string not digit, loop might be endlessly.